# ffmpeg segments are not working as expected

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to record rstp stream from an IP camera into ~10 mins chunks.

```
FFREPORT=file=$log_DIR/ffmpeg_recording.log \
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://$CAMERA_USERNAME:$CAMERA_PASSWORD@$IP:$PORT/stream1" \
-acodec aac -vcodec copy \
-f segment -segment_time 600 -min_seg_duration 300 -segment_atclocktime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format mp4 \
-strftime 1 "$cap_DIR/record_%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.mp4" \
-report -y
```

However, the video segments saved by ffmpeg are only ~1 min long, instead of 10mins.

Even the parameter for `min_seg_duration` of 5min is not respected.

Log file: https://pastebin.com/xNLYh5Vq

---

Reference: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment

originally posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76896277/3125466